# Assigning a value to a textbox that resides in another div using Jquery

Tags: jquery, textbox

I am using Jquery dialog box. There are two dialog boxes div1 and div2. There are 8 textboxes in div1 and I would like to update a specific textbox, txt6 when I change a value in div2.

I've tried the following but didn't work.

```
$("#div1.txt6").val('test');
```

Please let me know what I'm missing here.

Comment: Are `div1` and `div2` the ids of the elements?

Comment: Is `txt6` the name or ID of the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery custom events as follow:

1. When you change the value in div2, trigger an event:

   `$('#div2').val('something').trigger('valueChanged', { value: 'something' });`
2. In div1, subscribe to this event:

   `$('#div2').bind('valueChanged', function(e, args) {
     $('#txt6').val(args.value);
   });`

Answer (score 1):

If the textbox is inside `div1`, you need to do something like this:

```
$("#div1 #txt6").val('test');
```

I assume `txt6` is an identifier of the textbox; use `.txt6` instead of `#txt6` if it's a class.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to just assign an ID to the textboxes, than you can just target them directly.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you've got something similar to:

```
<div id="div1"> ... <input id="txt6" ... /> ... </div>
```

Try using:

```
$("#div1 #txt6").val('test');
```

jQuery uses css selectors to find things and when you pass "#div1 #txt6" jQuery looks for an element with id="div1" then it looks for an element that is a descendant of that result with id="txt6"

I'd recommend reading up on [css selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)